# How to Start Rails Server in Background from Command Prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 Application i am using Thin Server for running the project.Now i am starting Thin server from command prompt like:

```
c:<project_path> rails s
```

here the command prompt remains in my desktop ,if sometimes i close the prompt i have to restart it again.To avoid this i want to make the command prompt run in background.

Is it possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can `detach` (`-d` command line flag) your server from the console.

Comment: @VinTV, yes, it runs in development mode by default. Or do you mean it doesn't go background?